# Android GradientDrawable - Corner Radii issue

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter, cornerradius

I am trying to debug a problem I am having with ExpandableListAdapter.getChildView.

I have defined a Drawable with a shape containing a gradient and a corner with a radius of 1 for the background of the list item - nothing special there.

Then, in my adapter code, I have this snippet within getChildView:

```
GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) convertView.getBackground();
float topRadius = 0;
float bottomRadius = 0;

// Make the corner radius obvious for debugging             
if (childPosition == 0)
    topRadius = 14;
if (childPosition == (mValues.size() - 1))
    bottomRadius = 14;

background.setCornerRadii(new float [] { topRadius, topRadius, 
                                         topRadius, topRadius,  
                                         bottomRadius, bottomRadius, 
                                         bottomRadius, bottomRadius});
convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

The attempt here is to round the top of the first list item, and the bottom of the last list item.  Via debugging, it would appear that I am setting the values I want for the items that I want.

However, the problem I'm having is that the corner radii are being set for all list items as if it were the bottom item.

As a slight aside, is there a way to get the corner radii of the GradientDrawable, at least for debugging purposes?

Thanks,
wTs

Comment: not sure if this is relevant to you, just want to point out that there's a known bug with the radius, should always use 0.1f instead of 0 for corners you don't want to be rounded. see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=939 - but I think your way is the opposite, so it's probably something with the list adapter logic maybe.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get the corner radii, looking at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java#GradientDrawable. Have you tried to define the drawable in xml - just to see whether it makes a difference?

Comment: @Mathias: The basic drawable is in xml, but I need to modify the first and last item (only).

Comment: @WtS: I meant to use three drawables (top, middle, bottom) and put the logic in getView/bindView of the adapter. But I see you already got a solution, interesting link there from Romain, need to read through it myself... Cheers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of calling setCornerRadii(), call mutate().setCornerRadii(), that should fix your issue (full explanation available at http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/)

**Edit (by Wonko)**
This is almost correct (and the link provided does basically explain why).  The only change is that mutate() returns a Drawable, which does not have a setCornerRadii() method.  Instead, you need to cast the mutated object back to a GradientDrawable, and it works like a charm.

```
((GradientDrawable) background.mutate()).setCornerRadii(
    new float [] { topRadius, topRadius, topRadius, topRadius,  
                   bottomRadius, bottomRadius, bottomRadius, bottomRadius});
```

Comment: good answer, great link.  I did make one change to your answer (I still marked it as the answer) so anybody having this issue in the future has the information in one spot.

Comment: lol - just realized the link was your own.  Would upvote it twice if I could.  :)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Just realized this isn't a fix for the OP's problem.

In addition to Mathias's comment, a fix for this is to first set the radius to 1, then set the individual corner radii:

```
background.setCornerRadius(1.0f);
background.setCornerRadii(new float [] { topRadius, topRadius,  
                                         topRadius, topRadius,   
                                         bottomRadius, bottomRadius,  
                                         bottomRadius, bottomRadius});
```

Let me know if this fixes the problem. As far as getting the corner radii, I don't know of any way to do so...

Comment: Nope - see the solution and reason why from @Romain Guy (marked as answer)

Comment: Yup, I realized after reading Romain/your answer that mine wasn't the solution to this particular problem. Good stuff to know in the future! :)